# how to auto decrement a column in the database daily

Tags: php

I have a column name remainingDays.  This counts the remaining days since the last donation of the user.  How can I auto decrement this column daily. Example the column has a value of 90 then tommorow it becomes 99.  It automatically updates the database without users interaction.

Comment: I have tried putting a column lastDonation then I minus it to the day to day. And I works pretty fine but what I want is that without user interaction my system automatically updates database daily

Comment: If you using PHP, you can using UPDATE query. Your logic is when time is increment = your remainingDays decrement.

Comment: yes I am using a Laravel Framework but this it automatically updates the database without user interaction?

Comment: @JkAsentista You'd want a cron, but IMO you're going about this completely wrong. Store the date of the last donation, and **calculate** the remaining days off its value.

Comment: I already have a column for the lastDonation and I calculated it for the remainingDays it work fine because it updates the database when the user clicks the button...what I want is when the time hits at 12:00 AM without users interaction to the system the data will automatically update to the database

Comment: I assume that you can not do the job once a day, triggered by e.g.Cron. Since you **never can know whether you have already decremented the counter** it would be better to  store the end date/time of the license period and compare it with the current one.

Comment: jsut do the math, dont change it

Answer (score 0):

I would add a date field to the database.  Then each time a donation is made, update the date and reset the counter.

Then whenever you need to check or get the current value of the counter, just change your select using something like the TO_DAYS function in MySQL that converts a date to a number-of-days value.

SELECT CURRENT_COUNT - TO_DAYS(now())-TO_DAYS(date(LAST_DONATION)) as RESULT

So if the last update was made yesterday, the counter value would be reset to the beginning and yesterdays date would have been recorded.  If the value was set to 100, today when we do the select it would return 99 and in ten days it would return 90.

This is how I'd do it anyway and it assumes MySQL but I'm sure this type of functionality is available in most SQL database sever environments.

Comment: does this work automatically? I dont need to press the button to update to the database

Comment: I'm assuming your database is updated each time a donation is made.  When you go to select the current counter value, you can use this method to calculate what the counter value would be based on the number of days that have passed since the last donation.  So no, you wouldn't have to manually do anything assuming you are storing the date the last donation is made.

Comment: Im gonna explain everything.. This project is a Blood Donation ..each donor can donate 90 days since there last donation...the admin will update to the database there last donation and I do math to calculate the remaining days...what my problem here is the admin needs to click the update button to update the remainingDaysForDonation column in the database...what I want is that everyday when the clock hits 12 Midnight the database remainingDaysForDonation updates..no need for the admin to update the profile

Comment: Do you have any suggestions sir what would I use? Im using laravel as a framework

Comment: In this case, I would not keep the remaining days in the database at all.  When you want to display the remaining days, I would calculate the number of days since the last donation and subtract it from 90 and display the result.  While this doesn't store the remaining days anywhere, it provides the info you want without requiring an auto-update process.  If you must have something that updates a remaining days field, I suggest creating a cron that runs a script that will execute a query that does the update.  The latter sounds more complex than you need.

Comment: Since using laravel, which is a PHP framework.  In the PHP script you're using to display data, calculate the days remaining rather than storing it in a database.  Believe me, this is much simpler and more flexible than trying to maintain a counter.